# When installing an add-on to IIS, how can I verify the IIS WMI Provider is available?

Tags: iis, wix, windows-installer, wmi

Apparently the management piece of IIS - the IIS WMI provider - is installable separately from the IIS runtime.

I'd like to produce an installer for an add-on to IIS, and I know how to check for the existence of the IIS runtime in the WIX project.  But, the installer needs to do various management things, WMI things, and for that it needs not only IIS, but the WMI Provider for IIS.  Which as I said, may or may not be present.

In a WIX project, How do I check for the existence of the IIS WMI Provider, and how do I present a reasonable dialog to the user if the IIS WMI Provider is not present?

---

The installer already has a few MSI Custom Actions implemented in Javascript, and I can use

```
var iis = GetObject("winmgmts:root\WebAdministration");
```

...to check for the existence of the WMI Provider. It will fail (throw) if no WMI Provider is there.  I suppose I could use this to set a Property, and then check that Property in a Condition early on in the Product.wxs file.

is this going to work? any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the better way for this is still to browse the registry for appropriate setting. Another question is it's not always easy to find the right one. :)

For instance, my installer needs IIS6 compatibility to be enabled (for IIS 7 machines), in particular, IIS 6 WMI compatibility. This setting is located under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components, in a value called WMICompatibility. So, everything I should do is to author a [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) element to search for this value and check if it's 1.

In order to find the correct setting, I would search for the key all IIS parameters reside under (it might differ for each version of IIS, I'm not certain here), enable IIS WMI provider you need and see what was changed in registry. I suspect registry monitor software can help here a lot.

Comment: I thought of using the registry, because it's easier to set a property according to a registry search in a Wix project. but I had little faith that I'd be able to definitively determine what reg key to scan for, to determine that the WMI provider was present. Maybe one of the objects would be there, but not another.  And so on.  Too many possibilities and edge cases.  That's why I decided to use instantiation of the object via the moniker as the test for presence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, testing instantiation of the object via the moniker is going to work. It's a reasonable strategy, better than spelunking around in the registry.  It delivers the right result, all the time. Just catch the exception that occurs if the WMI provider is not available.